# How to make REST API deployed to heroku accessible only through rapidAPI

Tags: api, heroku, rapidapi

Salutations!

I have just completed my first REST API, deployed on heroku, and I decided it would be cool to make $0 a month through rapidAPI.

The rapidAPI testing dashboard passes the tests successfully - with one of their keys being a requirement for an API call.

However when I access the site on a browser or on Postman, there is no need for an API key and therefore no restrictions in get requests.

I have noticed that the test code makes a fetch request to the rapidAPI url for the project but how can I make the heroku url accessible only from rapidAPI?

I know it's extremely unlikely someone will find my heroku app url but it is technically possible.

I appreciate your time and insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RapidAPI provides 2 security features to support this:

- set `X-RapidAPI-Proxy-Secret`in the API Dashboard: this token is added in the **X-RapidAPI-Proxy-Secret** HTTP header for each request. You should validate this for every API call. This is the default measure in place.
- the list of **IP addresses** used by RapidAPI is provided: you can check/validate for every API call.

There might be Heroku Addon to help with the IP filtering, but those are typically enterprise-plugin (with associated cost).

Comment: I have an nginx proxy that handles the incoming, and I have added the list IP addresses mentioned in the RapidAPI [doc](https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/security-threat-protection#list-of-ip-addresses-used-by-rapidapi). However, when I test my API within the Rapid API website, I am getting 403. by looking at the nginx logs I have this:

 *1 access forbidden by rule, client: 70.55.66.121, server: __, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "SOME_HOSE", referrer: "SOME_REFERRER"


I am sure where the IP come from.

Answer (score 0):

> RapidAPI allows you to add secret headers and/or query string parameters to API requests. The RapidAPI proxy adds these secrets to every request, but are hidden from the API consumers.

Find more details in this page: https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/secret-headers-parameters